# Utility to allow choice of editors for a given file extension

Tags: windows, file-management

Before I write a utility (for Windows 7-10 32/64bit), is there something that will replace an existing OpenWith association to launch itself and display a menu of potential editors/tools to open the selected file?

Comment: If you write the utility, please come back here and post an answer that includes a description and link to your software.